# How to properly call an "upsert" using parameterized raw SQL to Postgresql in ActiveRecord?

Tags: ruby, sql, postgresql, active-record

I need to call an `upsert` to my Category table in PostgreSQL. My current solution uses the `exec_query` API in ActiveRecord, using binding.

What I got so far looks like this:

```
VERIFY_CATEGORY_SQL = <<SQL
  WITH sel AS (SELECT id FROM categories WHERE name=$1 AND source=$2),
  ins AS (INSERT INTO categories (name, source, created_at, updated_at) SELECT
    $3, $4, 'now', 'now' WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT * from sel) RETURNING id)
  select id from ins union all select id from sel
SQL
```

```
VERIFY_CATEGORY_SQL = <<SQL
  WITH sel AS (SELECT id FROM categories WHERE name=$1 AND source=$2),
  ins AS (INSERT INTO categories (name, source, created_at, updated_at) SELECT
    $1, $2, now(), now() WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT * from sel) RETURNING id)
  select id from ins union all select id from sel
SQL
```

```ruby
def verify_category_existence(name, source)
  ActiveRecord::Base.connection.exec_query(VERIFY_CATEGORY_SQL, 'SQL', 
    [[nil, name], [nil, source]]).first['id'].to_i
end
```

**Notes**

1. In order to make this work I needed to add `prepared_statements: true` attribute to my `database.yml` file.
2. <strike>Although I need to reuse my `name` and `source` parameters, I can't and have to duplicate them as parameters `$1, $3` and `$2, $4` respectively</strike> (Apparently this works fine...)
3. The method call seems a bit hackish, and I believe maybe it was not meant as a public method, and only intended for internal uses (hence the awkward `[[nil, x]...]` syntax and the `'SQL'` parameter, which apparently is for logging purposes)

What do you think of this solution?

Do you know of a better way to do this?

**Edit:**

I've received great responses to the SQL/Postgresql side of my solution, but I would love to also hear from our rubyists regarding the Ruby/ActiveRecord part of the solution - is this way correct? is there a better solution?

**Edit:**

Just found out that using `'now'` produced unexpected results - timestamp values were re-used rather than calculated on each insert. Changed it to `now()`, and it works better.

Comment: In regular `PostgreSQL` you could just re-use `$1` and `$2`; try it with `PREPARE` then `EXECUTE` in `psql`. So if you can't here, it's a Rails or Pg gem limitation. My main concern is that your insert-if-not-exists implementation is subject to race conditions; concurrently running statements will both insert rows. You'll need `SERIALIZABLE` isolation to prevent that (test and make sure that's enough, I think it is), or you'll need to `LOCK TABLE ... IN EXCLUSIVE MODE` first. See http://stackoverflow.com/q/17267417/398670

Comment: @CraigRinger, could you explain how to use `SERIALIZABLE`? Could you show me an example?

Comment: take a look at the link I provided, it has references to safe approaches to upsert. For `SERIALIZABLE`, see http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/transaction-iso.html . It's important to understand that if you use serializable isolation, it'll cause an *error* when you encounter a race condition, so your code must handle errors and retry the transaction.

Comment: Do I need to use `SERIALIZABLE` if I have a unique constraint on the relevant columns? Won't it be enough? If so, I should still expect a unique exception, and retry, right?

Comment: Your approach has been tried, many times before. You are not the first to think of it. The links I provided explain why it does not work in a concurrent environment. Here is the most important one. Read this. http://www.depesz.com/2012/06/10/why-is-upsert-so-complicated/

Comment: Thanks! I've read the post you mentioned. Maybe I misunderstood it, but if there are no DELETEs, race condition will result in _one_ of the transactions to fail on insert, in which case a retry will solve the issue. What am I missing?

Comment: If you have a unique constraint on (source, name) it's probably OK, see answer. But in that case, why do it such a complicated way? Just run the insert, and if it fails, select the ID of the existing row. If there's no unique constraint, you will get double inserts.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Statement, formatted readably:

```
WITH 
sel AS (
  SELECT id FROM categories WHERE name=$1 AND source=$2
),
ins AS (
  INSERT INTO categories (name, source, created_at, updated_at )
  SELECT  $1, $2, 'now', 'now'
  WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM sel) 
  RETURNING id
)
SELECT id FROM ins
UNION ALL
SELECT id FROM sel;
```

Dummy table:

```
CREATE TABLE categories (
    id serial not null PRIMARY KEY,
    name text not null,
    source text not null,
    created_at timestamp,
    updated_at timestamp,
    UNIQUE(name, source)
);
```

Demo, with three concurrent `psql` sessions:

- Session1: `PREPARE q(text,text) AS WITH ...`
- Session2: `PREPARE q(text,text) AS WITH ...`
- Session0: `BEGIN;`
- Session0: `LOCK TABLE categories IN ACCESS EXCLUSIVE MODE;`
- Session1: `EXECUTE q('n', 's');`
- Session2: `EXECUTE q('n', 's');`
- Session0: `ROLLBACK;`

One session will report:

```
regress=> EXECUTE q('n', 's');
 id 
----
  1
(1 row)
```

and one will report:

```
regress=> EXECUTE q('n', 's');
ERROR:  duplicate key value violates unique constraint "categories_name_source_key"
DETAIL:  Key (name, source)=(n, s) already exists.
```

So it might be OK if you have a unique constraint on `(name, source)` and are willing to retry errors, but if you don't have that unique constraint:

```
ALTER TABLE categories DROP CONSTRAINT categories_name_source_key;
```

then you'll get a double insert, because your `SELECT` for IDs can run on both sessions before either session executes the `INSERT`.

If you have a unique constraint, there's no point wasting your time with all this hoop jumping. You're better off just running the `insert` and if it fails, querying for the ID of the existing row.

Comment: I do have a unique constraint, but since the call is made many times a second, and the DB is on another machine, I'd prefer to make one round-trip to the server. I will add a retry to my code though. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

This is not so much an `UPSERT` as an insert-if-not-exists.  Nevertheless, the PostgreSQL manual [suggests using a procedure](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/plpgsql-control-structures.html#PLPGSQL-UPSERT-EXAMPLE):

```
CREATE TABLE category
( id SERIAL
, name TEXT
, source TEXT
, UNIQUE (name, source)
);

CREATE FUNCTION insert_category_if_not_exists(n TEXT, s TEXT) RETURNS SETOF category AS
$$
    BEGIN
        BEGIN
            INSERT INTO category (name, source) VALUES (n, s);
        EXCEPTION WHEN unique_violation THEN
            -- The row already exists; proceed...
        END;
        RETURN QUERY SELECT * FROM category WHERE category.name=n AND category.source=s;
    END;
$$
LANGUAGE plpgsql;

SELECT * FROM insert_category_if_not_exists('rose', 'evian');
```